# Asus UX31 ultrabook suddenly shuts down when below 50% battery

Tags: 14.04, power-management, shutdown, asus

I've heard over the years that this computer had issues with the BIOS settings but that by 13.10 it had been cleared. It never used to happen on 13.10 but now that I'm on 14.04 it started showing these symptoms.

What happens exactly is that on battery power it will work normally until near 50% then it either shuts down spontaneously or it freezes and the fan goes crazy until crashing.

Plugged in, it doesn't experience any problems. It's not a heat problem because of this since I run it at full power plugged in and no issues arise.

I tried looking in the logs but don't know exactly what to look for. I think that may be a good place to start but other than that, has anyone else seen this behavior or know how to fix it?

What other specs would be useful?

BIOS according to dmidecode -s bios-version: UX31E.210

Comment: I have a similar problem. Probably it is the memory controller issue that in some cases was fixed by unplugging the battery. In my case this never solved the problem. The issue is more likely to happen while I'm watching a video via a wifi conexion and/or the fan is on. I am using ubuntu 14.04 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux my bios is UX31E.214 with default values. I get the following error at start up: [ 4.744943] [drm:intel_dp_start_link_train] *ERROR* too many full retries, give up and the following warnings: dmesg | grep rning [

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for all the hints and tips on here. Like other's, I've had issues on my Zenbook UX21E for years, while it was running Windows 7. I never upgraded the OS for years, other than the traditional MS updates. Under windows, the issue was confined to sudden shutdowns while pulling the AC power. (Honestly, I just thought it was a short in the power connector, so I would just shut the unit down before unplugging.)

However, last week I put Ubuntu 14.04 on this machine, and the behavior got worse. Not only would it shut down when the power was pulled, but also after about 20 minutes of use. I installed sensors and stuck it in a while-do loop, and forced the machine to work hard by running Fraqtive animations.

Sure enough, when the power was less than 75% AND the heat was 80C, the machine turned off.

After reading this thread, I updated the firmware - that helped with the sudden shutdown after pulling the AC, but not when the 75%/80C limit was hit while on battery. The machine would still unexpectedly power off.

So - I opened up the back, and disconnected the battery for 5 minutes. After reconnecting and powering back up - I ran the sensors and Fraqtive test...

....the machine stayed up until the battery ran dry, regardless of the CPU temperature.

So, best guess is that it was a combination of issues: the outdated firmware was responsible for the sudden shutdown when yanking out the AC (for all the reasons stated above), and the disconnect/reconnect of the battery clearly reset some sort of low battery reading that was inaccurate. (Whether it was the firmware in the battery or the firmware in the Zenbook that was issuing the false positive, I couldn't say.)

At any rate, I'm back, and the machine is quite healthy. So, thanks again to everyone.

Rob

Comment: I'd like to point out that this was in fact the solution. I had given up on the laptop but tried doing this and finally, after years of shitty behavior, the laptop battery finally runs dry before powering off the machine. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I just want to share my experience with an ASUS battery:

Also my netbook suddenly turned off when it was under 30% battery. However I never had the fan and freezing problem. I went along with it for months until one day it never turned on unplugged. It seems they define a life cycle for the batteries. My battery suddenly stopped working while it could save energy for about two hours.

Anyway, if  you want to monitor your battery status, you can click on **Battery** under the power indicator to see detailed information about your battery:

[image: power indicator]

then, check the **Capacity** percent which is the ratio of *Energy when full* to *Energy (design)*. It will get lower and lower every time you recharge, until your battery will stop working some day.

[image: battery detailed status]

So consider replacing your battery.

Comment: great guess! I was hoping this was the case but the capacity is at 87% so that probably isn't the case :/ I'm going to more aggressively check battery metrics on ubuntu. I'm seeing the charge history and it very clearly just reaches 60% and dissapears indicating at least ubuntu software is not misrepresenting total charge.

Comment: bounty ended, still no solution. it's getting worse but still nothing helps. I'm out of ideas so will have to start using this laptop as a desktop. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: There’s no software solution. You’re experiencing the same as me. I asked my college friends who have ASUS laptops if they had the same experience on Windows. The answer was YES. So it seems there are problems with ASUS batteries.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, a reliable solution for unexpected shutdowns and hangs was discovered!

This seems to be working with any Asus laptop suffering from unexpected shutdowns and / or hangs while running on battery:

1. Add the following boot arguments *both* to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX in /etc/default/grub.cfg:

> intel_pstate=disable pcie_aspm=force acpi_osi=’Windows 2009′ acpi_os_name=’Windows 2009′

Don’t forget to execute `sudo update-grub` afterwards!

2. Install the package tlp from ppa:linrunner/tlp an set at least the following values in `/etc/default/tlp`

> CPU_SCALING_GOVERNOR_ON_BAT=ondemand
>   CPU_BOOST_ON_BAT=0
>   PCIE_ASPM_ON_BAT=powersave
>   RUNTIME_PM_ON_BAT=on

3. Shut down the device, carefully remove the bottom cover and detach the big battery (not the tiny CMOS battery) from the motherboard for five minutes. There are plenty of youtube videos showing how to safely disassemble the various Asus laptops. With certain power management settings on the OS side, the EC (Embedded Controller) goes crazy and thus needs resetting. The only way to reset it is to detach the battery for a few minutes.
4. From now on, shutdowns should be gone. Take care, however, not to *ever* use any live USB stick or installation / recovery CDs based on Linux and using the intel_pstate driver and / or the default BIOS settings for ASPM. If you try to, you will merely reproduce the problem once again, and will subsequently have to disassemble your Zenbook once again. There are a few sad cases, like reinstalling Ubuntu itself, where you will *have* to boot from a live USB utilizing the problematic intel_pstate driver. Only do so when running on AC, and please repeat Stage 3 (no matter how boring) of this manual once you are done.

P.S. Intel_pstate and the default ASPM bios settings eventually make the mobo’s Embedded Controller go crazy and persist in this state until the battery is detached from the motherboard. That’s basically how this problem is born.

Answer (score 0):

Your laptop is likely to be overheating. The state of the battery is not likely relevant to the problem.

Possible solutions:

1) Remove the dust from the laptop vents and insure that you are not covering the vents by placing the laptop on a soft surface like a blanket or cloth.

2) Move the laptop to a cooler environment

3) Obtain a laptop cooler to place the laptop on to increase airflow and reduce heat buildup.

Comment: You might also find this interesting: http://forum.notebookreview.com/asus/681314-zenbook-ux32vd-noise-heat-problems.html

Comment: Not a heat problem, it works fine plugged in for hours or even days. Adding that to the original post.

Comment: Can you add your BIOS version to the post? It might be helpful in the future.. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to register only at this forum to report about my experiences. I had problems with Ubuntu 18.10 shutting down accidentally when the battery level was below 40%. In other forums the setting Intels Virtualization Technology or V-dT in the BIOS is pointed out. I have tested these and can guarantee that there is no connection. The shutdowns are still happening. Now I have added the kernel parameters and can report that the following setting under /etc/default/grub does not fix the problem completely: (But fixes the keyboard led brightness and display brightnes handling of ubuntu)

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi='!Windows 2012' pcie_aspm=force drm.vblankoffdelay=1 i915.semaphores=1"
```

The only solution, in fact, is to open the UX31A and remove the battery for at least 5 minutes. Now, regardless of kernel parameters, the regular shutdown works when the battery reaches a critical level.

Good luck,
E. Yagmahan

My System:
UX31A - Ubuntu 18.10 Cosmic - Kernel 4.18.0 - BIOS Version 219